# Incrementing a counter in recursive function calls

Tags: javascript, recursion, foreach, counter

I'm struggling on how to increment a basic counter in javascript.

### What do I want to achieve ?

I need a counter inside a `foreach` loop. The goal is to be able to count each time the `//Write smthg` is triggered.

Below is the **updated** version of the code I'm using. For the moment, it returns weird sequences of numbers. I guess it is resetted each time the recursive loop is triggered. I do not know how to correct it, suppose it's a basic javascript problem but as I'm learning through experimenting and on my own, I sometimes need to ask question to the community.

```js
function walk(dir, counter = 0) {

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {

    let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);

    if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
      counter = walk(fullPath, counter);
      walk(fullPath, counter);
      console.log('dir');
    } else {
      let size = fs.statSync(fullPath).size; // Get size of file
      listFiles.write(fullPath + " (" + size + ")\n"); // Write file path and size into copyList.xml
      ++counter;
      console.log(counter);
    }

  });
  return counter;
}

walk(copyFrom); // Starts function "walk"
```

Sequences obtained :

```
2,3,4,5,6,7,dir,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,dir,11
```

### Here is the complete answer

```js
function walk(dir) {
  let n = 0;

  function walk(dir) {

    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {

      ++n;
      console.log(n);
      let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);

      if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
        --n;
        walk(fullPath);
        console.log('dir');
      } else {
        let size = fs.statSync(fullPath).size; // Get size of file
        listFiles.write(fullPath + " (" + size + ")\n"); // Write file path and size into copyList.xml
      }

    });
  }
  return walk(dir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my forEach is fine (it works in the full code version). Just made the edit.

Comment: n will reset to 0 each time you recurse. So your numbers can go something like so: `0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, ...etc`. If you want to have an iterator counting total number of iterations, you'll need to pass `n` into the function and default it to 0 (for the first iteration)

Comment: Yepp, that's exactly the problem I've got.  @mhodges. It may seem trivial but I can't get it right...

Comment: Check out my solution and see if that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper. The function `walk` makes the lexical variable `n` and a function `walk` that shadows the called fucntion for the duration of the recursive calls. It may have the original content of `walk` and the outer function just returns the result of calling it as itself was called.

```js
function walk(dir) {
  let n = 0; //Counter variable
  function walk(dir) {
    dir.forEach(file => {
      ++n;
      console.log(n);
      if (true) {
        //Recurse loop
      } else {
        //Write smthg
      }
    });
  }
  return walk(dir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but is false. Each time the recursive call is made, the counter is incremented however it should not be. I'll try to fix it and accept your answer as soon as it behaves as expected :)

Comment: @YouDeserveThat I only came with a slution to keeping the value not resetting. You need to **move** `++n` from counting all elementr regardless to just count the branch you want to count. I'm guessing from the OP inside the `else`.

Comment: Completely forgot about the use of helper functions - it's been a while since I've done any kind of heavy recursion. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

So, your issue is as follows:

Your counter will reset to 0 each time you recurse. So your numbers can go something like so: 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, ...etc. If you want to have an iterator counting total number of iterations, you'll need to pass your counter into the function and default it to 0 (for the first time `walk` is called), like so:

```js
var files = ["dir1-file1", "dir1-file2", ["dir1-sub1-file1"], "dir1-file3", ["dir1-sub2-file1", ["dir1-sub2-subsub1-file1"]]];

function walk(dir, counter = 0) {
  dir.forEach(file => {
    if (Array.isArray(file)) {
      // pass counter in to recursed function call
      // set current function counter to the result of the recursed function calls
      counter = walk(file, counter);
    } else {
      //Write smthg
      ++counter;
      console.log(counter);
      console.log(file);
    }
  });
  // return the counter for parent
  return counter;
}

walk(files);
```

Comment: That's quite it, but the number sequence is still confusing. I've updated the code above thanks to your answer.