# Javascript sum directory size inside a foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I'm having trouble with increasing a variable each time `forEach` is called.

The goal is to get the total size of a directory by summing the size of all the files inside it. The problem that I've got is to correctly understand where should I put the variables so that the correct size is computed.

Indeed, for the moment, the size calculated is the one of individual files instead of the total size. What am I missing ?

```
function walk(dir) {
  let
    n = 0,
    size = 0,
    totalSize = 0;

  function walk(dir) {

    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {

      let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);


      totalSize += size; //Total size ; should it be here ?
      ++n;

      console.log(size);

      if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
        --n;
        walk(fullPath);
      } else {
        size = fs.statSync(fullPath).size; // Get size of file
        listFiles.write(size + "\n"); // Write file size into copyList.xml
      }

    });
  }
  return walk(dir);
}
```

Current output :

```
340747217
18607
283163346
25332
287107119
22240
281853153
219100996
204879388
210185951
26321
278784426
21899
22695
238503727
29866
266805926
21697
285134805
```

Comment: So what line is supposed to sum all the sizes or add the current file's size to the sum?

Comment: I've commented the code above, sorry for forgetting that...

Comment: `size = +size` doesn't do anything other than convert the variable `size` to a number. Did you mean `size += size`? Even with that, you're overwriting the value later – you can't use the same variable to hold the current size and the total size at the same time.

Comment: Updated the code, is it better ?

Comment: Not much, because `totalSize` is a local variable that gets lost at the end of each iteration, and you're not doing anything with it anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... Another update, but it's still not working..

Comment: a function  called walk inside a function called walk is a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry @MarkSchultheiss it's based on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282360/incrementing-a-counter-in-recursive-function-calls

Comment: why not simply use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-folder-size   p.s. it's working asynchronous (:

Comment: Well, as I first needed to create a complete file list, I thought that adding individual file sizes would be a piece of cake to get total size.

Comment: @YouDeserveThat understood. try to execute this in terminal: `du -s YourPathHere | cut -f1`  (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calculating the total size in a wrong place and also the way of calculation is wrong. `size = + size` does not add new size into the existing value. Use a new variable to accumulate total size.(`totalSize`)

```
function walk(dir) {
  let n = 0,
     size = 0;
     totalSize = 0;

  function walk(dir) {
      fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
      let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
      ++n;

      if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
          --n;
          walk(fullPath);
      } else {
          size = fs.statSync(fullPath).size; // Get size of file
          totalSize += size; // Calculate total size
          listFiles.write(size + "\n"); // Write file size into copyList.xml
      }
    });
  }
  return walk(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel (:

There are tons of way to achieve that:

1) Calling command and getting output:

```
du -s YourPathHere | cut -f1
```

with JS:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('du -s YourPathHere | cut -f1', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  console.log(parseInt(stdout));
});
```

2) Simply use [get-folder-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-folder-size) module it's asynchronous out of box (does not use `*Sync` methods)

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getFolderSize = promisify(require('get-folder-size'));

(async () => {
  try {
    const size = await getFolderSize('/your-path');
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }  
});
```

or callback way:

```
const getFolderSize = require('get-folder-size');

getFolderSize(myFolder, (error, size) => {
  if (error) { 
    throw error; 
  }

  console.log(size);
});
```