# Get folder size in javascript

Tags: javascript, directory

What is the best method to get folder size in javascript platform-independent? (I don't want to use 'fs' & 'get-folder-size' as they use recursive methods which are not efficient with large hierarchal directories)

Note - I have a large directory and there will be multiple requests to get 'folder-size' hence I am looking for an alternate to recursive approach.

Comment: May be possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305633/javascript-sum-directory-size-inside-a-foreach

Comment: @JanakPrajapati My concern is completely different from this. I want to know if there is a non-recursive approach to get 'folder-size'. The above link suggests a contradictory recursive approach.